# Can a LCD monitor be used to log / monitor your activities?

Tags: security, display, lcd

I'm borrowing an LCD monitor from someone I don't completely trust, to use with my laptop.

Can the LCD monitor on its own be used to log the screens I view or websites I visit, or any other data? When I return the monitor, do I need to be concerned that he might know what I've been doing?

To be clear, the computer is my own, only the monitor is being borrowed and being used with the computer. Only the monitor will be returned.

P.S I'm in a big brother type of country.

Answer (score 4):

LCDs do not have the ability to record their output.

In *theory*, a LCD could be modified to do so, but it would be an extremely poor way to monitor your activities.  It would be far more efficient and effective to compromise your computer itself.

I dont think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: indeed. yes, it could be done. In reality its beyond hyper paranoid, and not at all trivial to do so.